# Exception Handler for Laravel 5 Packages

Tags: php, laravel-5, exceptionhandler

I want to write a separate `exception handler` for one `Laravel5` package, such that it displays the custom `404` view of that package.
Actually I want to know how should I register the `Exception Handler` of a package inside the provider of that package.

For example, if name of my package is `testPackage`, my `ExceptionHandler` file is located in :

```
vendor/testPackage/src/Exceptions/testExceptionHandler.php
```

And the `404` view file is located in :

```
vendor/testPackage/src/views/404.blade.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
{
    return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
}
return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

add this code in your testExceptionHandler.php